# ruby *args syntax error

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, args

I found this weirdness that I would like to understand. If I define these two methods in pry...

```
def test(*args)
   puts args
end
def test=(*args)
    puts args
end
```

they both work.But if I put the above code in a module and include that module in another class (say, class Job), the following

```
j=Job.last
j.test=(1,2,3)
```

throws the following error...

```
SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
j.test=(1,2,3)
          ^
```

The following work as expected...

```
j.test=[1,2,3]
j.test=(1)
```

So, it looks like inside the module, a method defined with an '=' always expects one arg. That doesn't make sense to me.

What am I missing

Answer (score 2):

Parsing of the Ruby interpreter. Try

```
j.send :test=, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: the above yields "undefined method `test=' for #<Job:0x007fdd3c844498>"

Comment: Try j.methods.include?( :test= ).

Answer (score 2):

use directly

```
j.test = 1,2,3
```

or

```
j.test= ([1,2,3])
```

or `

```
j.send('test=',[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Well, I've seen how to work 'with it', but why does 'test=' work from the pry command line but not from with in the module? Is this an error in ruby, or some fundamental misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: I told you: parsing of the Ruby interpreter. Complain on Ruby bug report site http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/